# Heroku, Django, and Sendgrid - emails not sending?

Tags: django, heroku, sendgrid

So I'm using heroku and sendgrid and think I have my settings.py configured correctly:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
```

I'm sending email using send_mail like this (using pre_save receiver to check if attribute has changed... also 'myemail@gmail.com' is replaced with my actual email):

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=LotteryEntry)
def send_email_if_invited(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    try:
        obj = LotteryEntry.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except LotteryEntry.DoesNotExist:
        #could send email here telling them when they should know
        pass
    else:
        if not obj.invited == instance.invited:
            l = Dinner.objects.get(id=instance.dinner.id)
            u = User.objects.get(id=instance.user.id)
            message = "You have been chosen to attend %s! Here is the description of the event: %s. We will see you there!" % (l.title,l.description)
            send_mail('You have been invited!',message,'myemail@gmail.com',[u.email],fail_silently=False)
```

The logs show that it is being sent.. but I'm not receiving it in my inbox nor does the sendgrid addon account section say I have sent emails. Anyone have this problem before?

Edit:

Here are my imports of settings.py

```
import os
import sys
```

And my models file (where send_mail happens):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import *
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.mail import send_mail
```

And here is a log of the send_mail call:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: MIME-Version: 1.0
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: You have been invited!
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: From: msencenb@stanford.edu
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: To: msencenb@stanford.edu
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Date: Mon, 28 May 2012 21:16:49 -0000
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <20120528211649.1.49209@2a33c2a2-9b5e-4da9-994c-15de8157702e>
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: You have been chosen to attend Web Development Pt. 1! Here is the descripti=
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: on of the event: Knight Management Center, 5/23/12 12:30 to 2 PM. We will s=
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: ee you there!
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 app[web.1]: [28/May/2012 16:16:49] "POST /admin/dinners/lotteryentry/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
2012-05-28T21:16:49+00:00 heroku[router]: POST morning-frost-2949.herokuapp.com/admin/dinners/lotteryentry/1/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=107ms status=302 bytes=0
```

Comment: did you checked spam? (as you sent it to gmail)

Comment: yes I did.. nothing in spam folder

Comment: Did you `import os` in your settings.py?

Comment: Also, logs and imports would be helpful.

Comment: Added in my logs + import statments

Comment: I tried my best to recreate your environment (although extremely simplified), and mine actually works fine.  Are you certain you didn't end up in the spam folder? Mine was flagged as spam http://www.evernote.com/shard/s196/sh/f825b48d-3006-43a1-9b00-3bdd759dc2a0/dc68373798201f1bb706144dfbc1aa57